# Save a resource received from API to a file

Tags: php, resources

I don't know if this is possible, so I am not really sure how to word this question. I am completely new to resources in PHP... Please forgive me if this sounds silly - I am all ears on suggestions on how to better this question.

I have been given code that makes an API call to a soap client. When it does this, an object is returned and part of that object is resources.

```
$myService = (object)array(
   'stuff' => MyCode::getClient('stuff_I_want_access_to')
);
```

When I print out 'stuff', I get something like this (some parts have been omitted as they aren't required for this question):

```
MyCode Object
(
    [_headers:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_stream_context] => Resource id #14
)
```

The issue with this particular code is that when I need to use it (which is often multiple times a day), I have to make these API calls for every command. This can take anywhere from 2-15 minutes depending on server load. To mitigate this wait time, I would like to save the objects returned from the API in some way so I can easily reference it later without making the API calls over again.

The issue I am running into is saving the resource. So far, anything I have tried does save all the keys, but it does not save the "Resource ID #14".Instead, it saves something like this:

```
[_stream_context] => 0
```

Is it possible to save resources? I am guessing that the Resource is really a pointer, but I don't know how that works.